# как переустоновить SQL server 2016 правильно?

Tags: sql, sql-server

с этого устоновщика устанавливал год назад вместе с visual Studio 17, вот недавно удалил оба так как проблемы были в visual studio, из-глупости удалил Microsoft Sql server 2016 тоже. При попытке установить заново все проходит кроме Служба ядра CУБД.

[image: Сбой при установке SQL Server 2016]

Как можно исправить??

Comment: Возьмите с официального сайта инсталлятор Express версии и установите, там и ошибки в случае чего будут поинформативнее.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov спасибо. я так и сделал. и всё прошло успешно без ошибок